# automatically wrapping text in scrollview?

Tags: iphone

i have displayed one text in UIview (through drawRect ) with UIScrollview.but when i zoom , the text goes ouside of the frame , i want to wrap automatically  , any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
[theText drawInRect: b withFont: f];
```